# Pythonの標準機能で、自由にプロパティを設定できるオブジェクトは？

Tags: python, python3

Pythonの標準機能で、任意の名前で、プロパティを設定できる仕組みを教えていただけないでしょうか。
以下のような事をしたいのですが、独自にクラスを作成しなければならないものなのでしょうか？
他によいスマートな方法を知りたいです。

```
class MyObject():  # ←わざわざ独自にクラスを作成しないで、dictのように自由にプロパティを設定したい。
    pass

obj = MyObject()
obj.x = 'AA'
obj.y = 'BB'
obj.z = 'CC'

print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z)
```

dictでは、プロパティの指定に鍵カッコで囲む必要がある。
namedtupleでは、設定可能なプロパティをあらかじめ指定しなければならない。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/types.html#additional-utility-classes-and-functions) が有ります。

```py
import types

obj = types.SimpleNamespace()
obj.x = 'AA'
obj.y = 'BB'
obj.z = 'CC'

print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z)  # AA BB CC
```

---

頭の体操としては、下のようにすれば、クラス定義せずに（作成はするが変数に束縛はしない）1行で独自クラスのオブジェクトを生成できます。

```py
obj = type("NameSpace", (object,), {})()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。types.SimpleNamespace()でできること、分かりました。

Answer (score 1):

[`class type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type) とか

```py
IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: X = type('X', (), dict(x='A', y='B', z='C'))

In [2]: X
Out[2]: __main__.X

In [3]: X.x, X.y, X.z
Out[3]: ('A', 'B', 'C')

In [4]: obj = X()

In [5]: [a for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('_')]
Out[5]: ['x', 'y', 'z']

In [6]: {a: getattr(obj, a) for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('_')}
Out[6]: {'x': 'A', 'y': 'B', 'z': 'C'}

In [7]:
```

他に,
組み込み関数ではないけど `argparse` の [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.Namespace) とか

```py
In [7]: from argparse import Namespace

In [8]: o = Namespace(bar='BAR', foo=True)

In [9]: o.bar
Out[9]: 'BAR'

In [10]: o
Out[10]: Namespace(bar='BAR', foo=True)

In [11]:
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。他にも方法があること分かりました。